# Is there an article/book where Niemytzki defined his plane?

Tags: gn.general-topology, ho.history-overview

In [2] (page 27) Engelking states that:

> The Niemytzki plane was defined (and attributed to Niemytzki), by Alexandroff and Hopf in [1]

which is accurate since in [1], where the plane is defined there is a footnote attributing that example to Niemytzki.

Does anyone know whether there is an article or book by Niemyzki where he defines the plane?

Bibliography:

[1] Alexandroff, P., Hopf, H., *Topologie I*, Berlin 1935.

[2] R. Engelking, *General Topology*, Heldermann Verlag, Berlin, Sigma Series
in Pure Mathematics 6, 1989.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V. Niemytzki, [Über die Axiome des metrischen Raumes](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002274779&physid=PHYS_0674) (1931) [see page 670]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful. I wonder if in this article it was the first time he defined it.

Comment: there is an earlier paper: V. Niemytzki, [On the third axiom of metric spaces](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1989093) (1927).

Comment: I checked this one before but it seems the plane is not defined there. BUT, I think the first reference you sent me (1931),  is kind of the second part of the other (1927). It's likely that the (1931) is the first time he defined on a paper. Thanks for your help.